# Django load huge data to drop down list (select) quicker?

Tags: django

I’m new to django, I have a application with search + drop down field where data load from database which contains 5000+ records, to load data it is taking 30-40 sec, this is not I expected.

Is there a better way to load data faster?

Any idea/thoughts/example appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: you could stop loading data before the search field get a value and a submit press to request  a sort of data. so low amount of data needs short time to load.

Comment: my requirement is that to show data in dropdown and user search the data inline before submit